# Реализация стека на Golang

Tags: алгоритм, golang

Пытаюсь реализовать простейший стек вызовов на Golang. В качестве образца взял код из книги "Грокаем Алгоритмы", код написан на втором Пайтоне.

```
def greet(name):
    print "hello, " + name + "!"
    greet2(name)
    print "getting ready to say bye..."
    bye()

def greet2(name):
    print "how are you, " + name + "?"
  def bye():
    print "ok bye!"
```

Вот моя попытка реализации на Го. Проблема состоит в том, что я не могу понять почему я не могу вложить функцию bye() внутри функции greet2 и вызвать в функции greet. Про скоуп уже прочитал, но вменяемых примеров там не было. Так что если вы сможете показать, как мне исправить этот код, я буду вам очень благодарен.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func greet(name string) string {
    fmt.Printf("hello, %v !\n", name)
    greet2(name)
    fmt.Printf("getting ready to say bye...\n")
    bye() // тут проблема
    return name
}

func greet2(name string) (func(), string) {
    fmt.Printf("how are you, %v ?\n", name)
    bye := func() { // и тут
        fmt.Println("ok bye!")
    }
    return bye(), name
}

func main()  {
    greet("Sasha")
    greet2("Sasha")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `bye()` на питоне не вложенная, в книге просто поехало форматирование (а для питона это катастрофа!). В python (да и не только) нельзя просто так взять и вызвать вложенную функцию из другой функции. Будет рантайм ошибка: `NameError: global name 'bar' is not defined` в том месте, где вы её попробуете вызвать.

На самом деле, код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
def greet(name):
    print "hello, " + name + "!"
    greet2(name)
    print "getting ready to say bye..."
    bye()

def greet2(name):
    print "how are you, " + name + "?"

def bye():
    print "ok bye!"
```

И уж его-то переписать на go, я думаю, у вас не составит абсолютно никакого труда.

---

Если вы всё же хотите пример со вложенной функцией и её возвратом, то вот как оно должно быть:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func greet(name string) {
    fmt.Printf("hello, %v !\n", name)
    bye := greet2(name) // функция greet2 вернула функцию
    fmt.Printf("getting ready to say bye...\n")
    bye() // тут мы вызвали эту функцию
}

func greet2(name string) func() {
    fmt.Printf("how are you, %v ?\n", name)
    bye := func() { // тут мы создали анонимную функцию и присвоили её переменной
        fmt.Println("ok bye!")
    }
    return bye // тут мы просто возвращаем переменную
}

func main() {
    greet("Sasha")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все понятно и просто. )

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть несколько ошибок. В одном случае Вы возвращаете не функцию, а её значение. В другом случае, функция `bye()` ещё не определена. [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jiwzOhtnnb3).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func greet(name string) string {
    fmt.Printf("hello, %v !\n", name)
    greet2(name)
    fmt.Printf("getting ready to say bye...\n")
    // Здесь функция bye не определена, поэтому её и вызвать нельзя
    // bye() // тут проблема 
    return name
}

func greet2(name string) (func(), string) {
    fmt.Printf("how are you, %v ?\n", name)
    bye := func() { // и тут
        fmt.Println("ok bye!")
    }
    // Здесь Вы пытаетесь вернуть результат, который выдаёт функция bye()
    // Нужно же возвращать саму функцию
    // return bye(), name
    return bye, name
}

func main()  {
    greet("Sasha")
    greet2("Sasha")
}
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Благодарю за помощь)